# visible table does not exist in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

In mysqlworkbench, I created a view, committed it to the database, but I no longer needed it.
As such, I deleted the view in mysql workbench and then updated the database.

I thought all was fine, however in phpmyadmin, it says that the table still exists. What's more, it is constantly in use.

I tried to drop the table within phpmyadmin, however when I try to drop the table, it provides an error message saying:

1051 - Unknown table ... indicating to me that the table is not there.

but it still remains showing in the database, and under collation, it says that the table is 'in use'.

Any advice here?

Comment: Is it a table or a view? this is not the same thing.

Comment: It's a view, but it looks like a table in phpmyadmin

Comment: Is your view still in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`?  Does it appear in the result of `SHOW TABLES`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

It appears as though you cannot delete a view from the database by normal means. The following solved the problem for me.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS viewName;
```